# Positioning 1000 roses in Blender

Tags: modeling, objects, topology, linked-data, blend-modes

I need to put 1000 roses on a 3D heart. See the images. I can make a heart and a rose and link duplicate it. But don't want to position each rose by hand. Is there a smarter way to do this? What procedure would you recommend?  Thank you.

[image: heart and roses]

Comment: Hello, have you tried a particle system?

Comment: or Geometry nodes. The intersection of the roses might be a problem

Comment: Geometry nodes was/is new to me. It looks that it will do the trick. Thanks a lot!